# sequence number vs version number in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am reading the concepts of elasticsearch-7.4 and I got to know about two fields. 
`_seq_no` and `_version`.

As per the documentation:

**Version**

```
Returns a version for each search hit.
```

**Sequence Numbers and Primary Term**

```
Returns the sequence number and primary term of the last modification to each search hit.
```

But it is not clearing anything related to when they both will be different or same for a document.

I created an index `test`

```
PUT /test/_doc/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "total_price" : {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "final_price": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "base_price": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  }
}
```

I am updating the full document using `PUT API`.

```
PUT /test/_doc/2
{
  "total_price": 10,
  "final_price": 10,
  "base_price": 10
}
```

Both ***_seq_no and _version are increasing*** in this case.

On doing partial updates using `UPDATE API`,

```
POST /test/_doc/2/_update
{
    "doc" : {
        "base_price" : 10000
    }
}
```

***Both _seq_no and _version are increasing*** in this case too.

So, I am unable to find the case when only one field is changing but the other is not. 
 
When will both the fields be different?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sequence numbers have been introduced in ES 6.0.0. Just before that release came out, they were very well explained in this [blog article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-sequence-ids-6-0).

But in summary,

- `version` is a sequential number that counts the number of time a document was updated
- `_seq_no` is a sequential number that counts the number of operations that happened on the index

So if you create a second document, you'll see that `version` and `_seq_no` will be different.

Let's create three documents:

```
POST test/_doc/_bulk
{"index": {}}
{"test": 1}
{"index": {}}
{"test": 2}
{"index": {}}
{"test": 3}
```

In the response, you'll get the payload below.

```
{
  "took" : 166,
  "errors" : false,
  "items" : [
    {
      "index" : {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "d2zbSW4BJvP7VWZfYMwQ",
        "_version" : 1,
        "result" : "created",
        "_shards" : {
          "total" : 2,
          "successful" : 1,
          "failed" : 0
        },
        "_seq_no" : 0,
        "_primary_term" : 1,
        "status" : 201
      }
    },
    {
      "index" : {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "eGzbSW4BJvP7VWZfYMwQ",
        "_version" : 1,
        "result" : "created",
        "_shards" : {
          "total" : 2,
          "successful" : 1,
          "failed" : 0
        },
        "_seq_no" : 1,
        "_primary_term" : 1,
        "status" : 201
      }
    },
    {
      "index" : {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "eWzbSW4BJvP7VWZfYMwQ",
        "_version" : 1,
        "result" : "created",
        "_shards" : {
          "total" : 2,
          "successful" : 1,
          "failed" : 0
        },
        "_seq_no" : 2,
        "_primary_term" : 1,
        "status" : 201
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see:

- for all documents, version is 1
- for document 1, `_seq_no` is 0 (first index operation)
- for document 2, `_seq_no` is 1 (second index operation)
- for document 3, `_seq_no` is 2 (third index operation)

Comment: Are you saying that seq_no is index specific,  not document specific?

Comment: The sequence numbers are scoped at the shard level, not at the document level. https://thihara.github.io/Introduction-ElasticSearch/

Answer (score 4):

### Elasticsearch documents are immutable

`Elasticsearch` documents are immutable, this means that whenever you update a document, a new version of that document will be **created**, regardless of whether you are using `PUT` (updating the entire document) or `POST` (updating some parts of the document).

Each newly created document will be given a new incremented **version**, which is identified by the `_version` field:

```
{
    "_index": "movies",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "109487",
    "_version": 14,
    "result": "updated",
    "_shards": {
        "total": 2,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "_seq_no": 17,
    "_primary_term": 7
}
```

### Blog website

Imagine that you have a blog website, and there are **2** users were hitting the same blog post of id **1** **at the same time**:
GET https://myblog.com/posts/1

Back to `Elasticsearch`, the `post` document has a field named `view_count`, this field stores the total number of views (*how many times the post was viewed*).

To increment the `view_count` you have to send a `GET` request reading the current value:

```
GET /posts/_doc/1
{
    "_index": "movies",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "109487",
    "_version": 12,
    "_seq_no": 15,
    "_primary_term": 7,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "post": "Lorem ipsum ...",
        "title": "My title",
        "published_at": "2020-01-01",
        "view_count": 10
    }
}
```

Then you update the `view_count` of post id **1** by incrementing the returned value (from `GET`) by **1**:

```
PUT /posts/_doc/1/_update
{
    "doc": {
        "view_count": 11
    }
}
```

**There is a problem here**.

Since both users were hitting the same post page at the same time, they’ll be getting the value of `10`.

As you see here, the value **11** was stored, but that is incorrect, since we updated the document twice (*remember 2 users hit the post id at the same time*), hence the value should be **12**.

But why? That is because both users have gotten the value `10` when they read the `view_count`.

So, how do we solve this issue?

Fortunately, Elasticsearch uses something called **Optimistic concurrency control** (**OCC**)  ([Optimistic concurrency control - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control)).

To ensure that the recent document needs to be updated we send the `if_primary_term` alongside with the `if_seq_no` values (which are fetched from the `GET` request):

```
POST /posts/_update/1?if_primary_term=1&if_seq_no=10
```

That’s it.

Comment: just for completeness:  this OCC solution will make one of the POST succeed, and the other will fail.  That still means that when both users are viewing the same blog, the view counter will be increased only once. So you need to handle that failed POST.

Comment: You're right @Allie 
The OCC won't solve the blog issue, but it will prevent requests from overwriting each other.