# Difference between version=1&version_type=external and if_seq_no=0&if_primary_term=1

Tags: elasticsearch, optimistic-concurrency

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58762025/2361308), it's clearly to say:

- version is a sequential number that counts the number of time a document was updated;
- _seq_no is a sequential number that counts the number of operations that happened on the index, which is used with `primary_term` to uniquely determine the version on the index;

However as a user, is there any difference between `version=1&version_type=external` and `if_seq_no=0&if_primary_term=1` to achieve concurrency control?

My understanding is that:

- to achieve "external" concurrency control, `if_seq_no=0&if_primary_term=1` can be a little more inconvenient since we have to record two fields at the same time in DB while we only need to record `version` as to `version=1&version_type=external`.
- as for "internal" concurrency control, `if_seq_no=0&if_primary_term=1` will improve the parallelism level while `version` is comparably worse.

Are these two conclusions right? If right, why specifically?

---

I did some simple experiments in ES 7.4.2 as follows:

```
POST test/_bulk
{"index": { "_id": 1 }}
{"test": 1}
{"index": { "_id": 2 }}
{"test": 2}

PUT test/_doc/1?version=1&version_type=external&error_trace=true 
{
  "test": 1
}

GET test/_doc/1

PUT test/_doc/1?if_seq_no=0&if_primary_term=1&error_trace=true 
{
  "test": 1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this old post [Elasticsearch Versioning Support](https://www.elastic.co/cn/blog/elasticsearch-versioning-support), I see that `_version` is used in ES for concurrency control.

While in [Breaking changes in 6.7](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/breaking-changes-6.7.html#breaking-changes-6.7), I might just quote here.

> internal version may not uniquely identify a document’s version if an indexed document wasn’t fully replicated when a primary fails. As such it is unsafe to use for optimistic concurrency control, is deprecated and the option will no longer be available in Elasticsearch 7.0.0. Please use the if_seq_no and if_primary_term parameters instead.

So basically the answers are:

- we could use them both as "external" concurrency control if we have external versioning system;
- while "internal" concurrency control for ES, we should use `if_seq_no=0&if_primary_term=1` as the only option.