# Is it possible to pass document version in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

This is the version I use, got it using kibana devtools:

```
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.2",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "unknown",
    "build_date" : "2023-03-12T18:08:54.377848Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.10.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  }
```

My logic sometimes makes an update of the documents using query api, we just update one field of the document, by doc id.

This is what I got for one of such updates:

```
{
    "took": 19,
    "timed_out": false,
    "total": 1,
    "updated": 0,
    "deleted": 0,
    "batches": 1,
    "version_conflicts": 1,
    "noops": 0,
    "retries":
    {
        "bulk": 0,
        "search": 0
    },
    "throttled_millis": 0,
    "requests_per_second": -1,
    "throttled_until_millis": 0,
    "failures":
    [
        {
            "index": "orders_v3",
            "type": "_doc",
            "id": "B6140D17-5E74-4852-AD3A-74A17016A12B",
            "cause":
            {
                "type": "version_conflict_engine_exception",
                "reason": "[B6140D17-5E74-4852-AD3A-74A17016A12B]: version conflict, required seqNo [23387862], primary term [1]. current document has seqNo [24968865] and primary term [1]",
                "index": "orders_v3",
                "shard": "2",
                "index_uuid": "Nby7jlqiRnywtcipttr25A123"
            },
            "status": 409
        }
    ]
}
```

By checking logs I noticed that 4 seconds before this there was another update of the document where we did not have `refresh:true` passed. I suspect this causes the issue.

Our refresh_interval os set to 7 seconds now.

I'd like to know whether it's possible to pass the document version number with each update so elastic could see that version and merge the documents in the order of version received.

So when parallel requests happen or the one that happened in my case, would be easily resolved by the version passed with the document.

Is there a way to implement it or maybe something similar that would fix the issue?

Comment: You need to read more about [optimistic concurrency control](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.9/optimistic-concurrency-control.html)

Comment: @Val, I appreciate your time answering me but this doc page, which I have already read, can hardly be considered helpful enough. It does not give any examples or suggestions that could be used in real situations which I described.

Comment: Towards the end of the document, it says that you simply need to pass `if_seq_no= 23387862&if_primary_term=1` if you want your update calls to succeed.

Comment: @Val, I was looking for the ways not to make extra GET call before the update operation. Moreover, these params only instruct whether to update the document or not while I was looking for a way to always update it but correctly "merge" documents if the same attributes are updated, so latest payload would be used.

Comment: Each time you update a document, the response will include the `_seq_no` and `_primary_term` to use if you want to update the document again, so that's what you need to do, whether refresh or not.

Comment: @Val, I read this comment of yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58762025/13584912 and it seems like seq_no is an index level counter, not document. So when document is updated and seq_no is returned, there are other updates of other documents which increase the seq_no counter on the index level. How should it meet the condition `if_seq_no= 23387862` in such case? Can you clear this up for me, please?

Comment: `_seq_no` is a shard level counter. the sequence number you provide must always be bigger than the one currently stored with the document, if it's lower it means you're trying to override a newer version of the document.

Comment: @Val, so ifI get the error like this: `[B6140D17]: version conflict, required seqNo [23387862], primary term [1]. current document has seqNo [24968865] and primary term [1]`, this means that doc was updated long time ago, it was assigned the 23387862 seq_no. "a few days later", I tried to update the doc again, under the hood it made the GET operation to retrieve seq_no of this doc, and tried to update it but this seq_no was already lower than the shard level seq_no counter which is 24968865, is that so ?